# Is it possible to add an svg image for when a d3 chart returns no data?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, d3.js

For the following plunkr, I have a pie chart that has 3 pie wedges. When there is no data, the pie chart goes away and displays a custom string '0 incidents'. This was done in the noData property of the chart configuration:

```
 noData: '0 incidents'
```

My Question is rather than display a string, how can I insert an empty pie chart as an indicator of no data like in the following [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/o7JHopGCPImOol4uVxuQ?p=preview)?

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['nvd3']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'pieChart',
            height: 500,
            x: function(d){return d.key;},
            y: function(d){return d.y;},
            noData: '0 incidents',
            color:['#CE1B1F', '#FFC455', '#00A6CD'],
            showLabels: false,
            duration: 500,
            labelThreshold: 0.01,
            labelSunbeamLayout: true,
            legend: {
                margin: {
                    top: 5,
                    right: 35,
                    bottom: 5,
                    left: 0
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
            contentGenerator: function (e) {
              var series = e.series[0];
              if (series.value === null) return;

              var header = 
                "<thead>" + 
                  "<tr>" +
                    "<td class='legend-color-guide'><div style='background-color: " + series.color + ";'></div></td>" +
                    "<td class='key'><strong>" + series.key + "</strong></td>" +
                  "</tr>" + 
                "</thead>";

              var rows = 
                "<tr>" +
                  "<td class='key'>" + series.key + '- #3: ' + "</td>" +
                  "<td class='x-value'>" + e.data.MyAttribute1 + "</td>" + 
                "</tr>" +
                "<tr>" +
                  "<td class='key'>" + series.key + '- #5: ' + "</td>" +
                  "<td class='x-value'>" + e.data.MyAttribute2 + "</td>" + 
                "</tr>";

              return "<table>" +
                  header +
                  "<tbody>" + 
                    rows + 
                  "</tbody>" +
                "</table>";
            } 
          }                

        }
    };

    $scope.data = [
        {
            key: "CAT I",
            y: 2,
            MyAttribute1:"DLA Avn ... CAT I",
            MyAttribute2:"DLA Energy ... CAT I"
        },
        {
            key: "CAT II",
            y: 1,
            MyAttribute1:"DLA Avn ... CAT II",
            MyAttribute2:"DLA Energy ... CAT II"
        },
        {
            key: "CAT III",
            y: 3,
            MyAttribute1:"DLA Avn ... CAT III",
            MyAttribute2:"DLA Energy ... CAT III"
        },
    ];
});
```